# 404 (Not Found) bootstrap in app.js with Laravel 10 + Vite

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, vite

I'm using Laravel 10 + Vite to develop my app. But when I use Vite build, and load to my blade such as:

```
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

I got error  404 not found in Bootstrap. Here's my app.js on `/resources/js/app.js` :

```
import './bootstrap';
window.Echo.private('chat')
  .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
    this.messages.push({
      message: e.message.message,
      user: e.user
    });
  });
```

And here's my package.json :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "watch": "vite build --watch",
        "build-rtl": "rtlcss public/build/css/app.min.css"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.15.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
        "pusher-js": "^8.4.0-rc2",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vite-plugin-static-copy": "^0.16.0",
        "vue": "^3.4.19"
    }
}
```

Any solution? thanks !

working Bootstrap script on my app.js with Laravel 10 + Vite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved when I running  `npm run dev`

I another terminal too with `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

ok, i suggested you use absolute path in your code.

```
import '/resources/js/bootstrap';
```

for more info see this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032511/warning-failed-to-decode-downloaded-font-warnings-after-building-a-react-app-v/78032632#78032632)

Comment: Hi still error not found when I running npm run build

Comment: could you show your directories of projrct?

Comment: └── public
    └── .htaccess
    └── build
        └── .vite
        └── css
        └── fonts
        └── icons
        └── images
        └── js
            └── app.js
            └── bootstrap.js
            └── chat.js
            └── components
            └── pages
        └── lang
        └── libs
            └── wnumb
    └── favicon.ico
    └── index.php
    └── robots.txt


my directory of public